# How can I reorder the objects in a javascript array?

Tags: angularjs

I have retrieved an array of test objects:

```
self.tests = response.data.tests;
```

The test objects that make up the array have a `title` and a `modifiedBy` field.

Is there some way that I can reorder the array by title ascending and then modifiedBy descending?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following

```
self.tests.sort(function(a, b) {
     var diff = a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
     return diff == 0? b.modifiedBy.localeCompare(a.modifiedBy) : diff;
});
```

**Example**

```js
var arr = [

  {"title" : "title1", "modifiedBy" : "david1"},
  {"title" : "title1", "modifiedBy" : "david3"},
  {"title" : "title2", "modifiedBy" : "david2"},
  {"title" : "title1", "modifiedBy" : "david2"},
  {"title" : "title2", "modifiedBy" : "david1"}
]

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var diff = a.title.localeCompare(b.title);
  return diff == 0? b.modifiedBy.localeCompare(a.modifiedBy) : diff;
});


console.dir(arr);
```

Comment: I am getting a message saying localeCompare does not exist on type number. Note that I am using typescript and modifiedBy is a number. Thanks

Comment: @Alan - I assumed `modifiedBy` as string. You need to change from `b.modifiedBy.localeCompare(a.modifiedBy)` to `b.modifiedBy - a.modifiedBy`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort data in js code, @nikhil's answer is great.

As I saw you have the `angularjs` tag in your question, if you want to sort data in template, it would be much easier. Here is the tip (replace `+` with `-`, if you want sort in reversed direction):

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in tests | orderBy: ['+title','+modifiedBy']>
   Title: {{obj.title}}
   Modified By: {{obj.modifiedBy}}
</div>
```

Comment: That's how you do it in angular :)